# pjax, eldarion-ajax and regular requests together in one website - is it normal?

Tags: python, django

I need your suggestion for best practices.
I use in one website based on django the follow type of requests:

1. pjax (pushState + ajax) - for site navigation with changing url and working browser buttons
2. eldarion-ajax - for forms POST, table pagination, sorting and other GET requests with parameters
3. regular request - if users wants a direct access to url instead menu navigation based on pjax

Is it normal to use all together in one website?
Maybe some technologies not recommended to use or it should be combined?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question, no this is not generally normal and you probably should't be using multiple ajax packages in your project. I honestly can not think of a reason why you would want to use multiple. You should only use one ajax package, I am not familiar with the two packages you listed but I am willing to assume that both do the same thing and there is no need to have two different packages for different request types. It sounds like you might fully understand what these packages do. Ajax will submit or get data without a page reload, request does the same thing but with a page reload. requests are the traditional way data has been transmitted. Ajax is a newer way and is used on many new websites. If you are new to website development, I would encourage you to stick with requests until you get the basics down. requests will work out of the box and you can just use django without any other configuration. If you want to use ajax then you will need to deal with csrf tokens which is explained in the django docs. There are some use cases where ajax would be preferred such as use a standalone javascript front end such as Vue, in this case you would make ajax calls to the django rest backend. Django has pagination built in so there is no need to use an outside library in most cases. There are many ways to deal with state and that would be better suited for another question.

tldr:

- Dont use multiple ajax libs there is no need.
- If you are using django templates and are just learning django use requests.
- If you are using a stand alone front end such as Vue you will need some sort of ajax lib.
- Django has built in pagination